# Interrelation between two component Angular?

Tags: angular

There are two components with the following structure:

```
<app-root>
    <app-book-list>
    <app-pagination (onSelect)="setPageSize($event)">
<app-root>
```

Method that loads books from server is placed in `<app-book-list>`:

```
public getBooks(page: number): void {}
```

When user select page from pagination it invokes event `(onSelect)="setPageSize($event)"`.

Handler `setPageSize()` is in `<app-root>` component.

```
 public setPageSize(badge: Badge): void {
     // Call here getBooks
 }
```

How to call method `getBooks()` inside `public setPageSize(badge: Badge) {}`?

Sure, I can move component `<app-pagination (onSelect)="setPageSize($event)">` into `<app-book-list>`, but I want to use list anywhere else so that why I separated pagination from list component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be two ways of approaching this:

1. build a service with observables that will handle values and some functions
2. use the @Input() and @Output() to communicate between parents and children

In any case, you need to think about your use case. For greater reusability I would personally go with a dedicated service.

Comment: Could you provide a sample for my case? Do you mean pass function getPage as Ipnut of list component?

Comment: In your specific case, the easiest way would be to build a service that will contain all yoru functions to be called in multiple components. Create a service folder, in it do `ng g s yourServiceName` and then put your function inside. From your component, declare it in the `constructor` and then call your function in your component

Comment: Do you mean dont use input, output but use service with observable funcitn that detects page changed?

Comment: You have several ways to go. If you need to only call a function, there is no need for observables. Just put your function in a service and call it from there. You should use @Input() for function calls

Comment: Could you share an example for this case: `build a service with observables that will handle values and some functions`

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/